# andEngine Can't get ACTION_UP in onSceneTouchEvent

Tags: android, andengine

I'm having some issues with the Scene Touch Listener. I only receive ACTION_DOWN events. I never get ACTION_UP or ACTION_MOVE events. What i did it wrong?. Please help me .

I have overridden the onSceneTouchEvent as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(final Scene pScene,
        final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {
    switch (pSceneTouchEvent.getAction()) {
    case TouchEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        Log.d(TAG, "onSceneTouchEvent # ACTION_DOWN");
        break;
    case TouchEvent.ACTION_UP:
        Log.d(TAG, "onSceneTouchEvent # ACTION_UP");
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

*notice :I return true already but it still get only ACTION_DOWN

Comment: Well, that's strange. Can't see anything wrong here and I used something similar - although  my scene wasn't final. But that shouldn't be it. Have you tried checking the motion event? Something like `if(event.getAction() == motionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)`   or  `if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)`. Would be interesting if this one is registered.

Comment: oh, sorry, just realized you already said that.

Comment: Thank you very much for replying.

I did it following your solution but It still have the same problem. (T_T)

Comment: Put the following in front of the switch statement: Log.i("Logged TouchEvents", ""+pSceneTouchEvent.getAction()); Which actions are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

never use switch case. because it will choose only one case, and action down is the first action, it will choosen forever.. the other action will ignored.

use this instead:

```
if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown){
   //code action down here
}
if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionMove){
   //code action move here
}
if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp){
   //code action up here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you listening to scene touch events anywhere else? It could be that you are listening to action up and handling it there (returning true) before it propagates to this listener.